# Login by code seems to not work in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-backpack

Basically i'm trying to send by email a link that lets you login with a specific account and then redirects you to a page.

I can seccessfully generate link and send them via email using URL functionalities in laravel using this code:

Generating the link:

```
$url = "some/page/".$travel_id;
  $link = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
     'autologin', now()->addDay(), [
         'user_id'       => 3,
         'url_redirect'  => $url,
     ]
 );
```

And sending the mail:

```
Mail::send('emails.travel', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
     $message->from('mail@mail.com', 'blablabla');

     $message->to('reciever@mail.com', 'blablabla')->subject('test');
  });
```

There is a route that catches the link sent by mail that is supposed to log you in with the user (in this case, the one with the id '3') and redirect you to some page but when it redirects, it prompts you to the login page, as if you are not logged.

Here is the route:

```
    Route::get('/autologin', function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);
    if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(403);
    }

    Auth::login($user);   
    return redirect($request->input('url_redirect'));
})->name('autologin');
```

When i try to do a `Auth::check()` after the `Auth::login($user);` it returns true, so is the user logged in?

I also tried to use `Auth::loginUsingId($request->user_id);` with no different results.

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Normally, it's a bad idea to send the user id in an email over the internet. You could try to place the user login logic in middleware this may help, as I'm not sure the Auth::login works inside a controller function. But I could be wrong about that.

Comment: You may want to check gaurd too `Auth::guard('admin')->login($user);`

Comment: Please check the value of your applications cookie session lifetime in config/session.php

Comment: @JamesHudson That's a good observation, turns out i don't need to send the user id at all for what i'm doing. I also found the solution to my problem and i will be posting the answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the problem,

I was logging in with a backpack user but i was using the default auth feature of laravel.

Turns out i need to use: `backpack_auth()->login($user);` instead of `Auth::login($user);` if i want to login using a backpack user.

Also use `backpack_auth()->check()` instead of `Auth::check()`.